# How does Math.Random in Java create random numbers

Tags: java, random, minecraft

I was wandering how I can create my own random number generator for reverse engineering mc seeds by setting starting conditions such as time .thank you in advance.

Comment: "*How does Math.Random in Java create random numbers*" - [Why not take a look at the source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Random.java)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Math.random calls an object of type Random, [Source](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java#L809)
2. `nextDouble` is called, [Source](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java#L809)
3. `nextDouble` is implemented like this:

```
public double nextDouble() {
   return (((long)(next(26)) << 27) + next(27)) * DOUBLE_UNIT;
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Random.java#L531)

DOUBLE_UNIT is private static final double DOUBLE_UNIT = 0x1.0p-53; // 1.0 / (1L << 53) [Source](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Random.java#L92).

4. `next` is implemented like this:

```
protected int next(int bits) {
        long oldseed, nextseed;
        AtomicLong seed = this.seed;
        do {
            oldseed = seed.get();
            nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
        } while (!seed.compareAndSet(oldseed, nextseed));
        return (int)(nextseed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Random.java#L198)

As you can see, it's a

> linear congruential pseudorandom number generator